# Corrupted .ttf files when extracting embedded fonts from PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, embedded-fonts

I managed to create a piece of C# code that **extracts embedded fonts from a PDF file**.  I am testing it with documents that have TrueType fonts embedded.

The problem is that when I write the font bytes into a file, **I cannot open it with any font viewer as it seems to be corrupted**.

The funny thing is that the code seems to be quite OK, as executing [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) `mutool.exe extract` I get the same exact files with the same result (corrupted .ttf files).

Here's the code (sorry, it's quite large, but I found no shorter way to achieve this so far):

```
public void ExtractFonts(PdfReader reader, PdfParserDocument document)
{
    foreach (var fontData in BaseFont.GetDocumentFonts(reader))
    {
        // Get font name and indirect reference
        var name = (string)fontData[0];
        var reference = (PRIndirectReference)fontData[1];

        // Get font bytes from PDF
        var XrefIndex = Convert.ToInt32(reference.Number.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var fontDictionary = (PdfDictionary)reader.GetPdfObject(XrefIndex);
        var fontDescriptor = fontDictionary.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR);

        PRIndirectReference fontBytesReference = null;

        if (fontDescriptor != null)
        {
            if (fontDescriptor.Get(PdfName.FONTFILE) != null)
            {
                fontBytesReference = (PRIndirectReference)fontDescriptor.Get(PdfName.FONTFILE);
            }
            else if (fontDescriptor.Get(PdfName.FONTFILE2) != null)
            {
                fontBytesReference = (PRIndirectReference)fontDescriptor.Get(PdfName.FONTFILE2);
            }
            else if (fontDescriptor.Get(PdfName.FONTFILE3) != null)
            {
                fontBytesReference = (PRIndirectReference)fontDescriptor.Get(PdfName.FONTFILE3);
            }
        }

        // Only add embedded fonts
        if (fontBytesReference != null)
        {
            var fontBytesReferenceIndex = Convert.ToInt32(fontBytesReference.Number.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            var pdfObject = reader.GetPdfObject(fontBytesReferenceIndex);
            var pdfStream = (PdfStream)pdfObject;
            var bytes = PdfReader.FlateDecode(PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)pdfStream));

            // Write to file
            using (var file = File.OpenWrite(name + ".ttf"))
            {
                file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially PDF does only require very few basic font information, and many pdf generators only embed these basic information. For generic font use these basic information do not suffice.

Comment: It seems that SourceForge is able to extract all fonts from the same PDF files, so I guess that font information within PDF document does suffice, :-)

Comment: "SourceForge" is able to extract all font. Er... SourceForge is a hosting provider for open source projects: http://sourceforge.net/support It doesn't extract fonts from a PDF. Also: extracting fonts from a PDF is in many cases in violation with the license of the fonts that were used in the PDF, so you may be doing something that is illegal.

Comment: Dammit!  Sorry, I meant "FontForge", my brain seems to be playing with my fingers while typing...

Comment: In that case it looks like iTextSharp and MuPDF both return exactly the font file as embedded in the PDF while FontForge changes it, enriching it with additional information required for a whole font file.

Comment: Sure.  I wish I was more fluent in C to understand how FontForge does the trick...  I'll let stackoverflow know if I find out.